# Is possible to make Step Functions wait for messages in SQS to be empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

In the Amazon SQS queue there are many of messages. Is it possible in the AWS Step Functions workflow receiving message from the SQS queues until empty then continue the workflow?

[image: here the workflow here]

Comment: You'd probably need to use an AWS Lambda function to check the CloudWatch Metrics on the queue. Can you tell us more about your situation? _Why_ do you want to wait for the SQS queue to be empty?

Comment: because we need all data from process in receiving messages in queue before process flow in lambda2

Comment: You'll probably need to create a loop that calls an AWS Lambda function to check the metric. If the queue is not empty, configure Step Functions to wait a while before looping again.

Comment: You could do this without step functions, if you don't want to use them.